# Is there a way to transform my function to standard ODE function in DifferentialEquations.jl in julia?

Tags: julia

I want to build the ODE function by my own function, and this function can be fed into ODEProblem in DifferentialEquations.jl.

Here is a simplified example.
I have two structs VariableA & VariableB, and I use them to generate A, B.
Finally, I want to use A, B to generate the ODE function.
A has a main differential equation, and I want to add B into A dynamically.
It means that there can be 0 or 1 or 2 or more B components in A.
I have no idea where to start with.
Can I accomplish the idea? Is there any suggestion?

```
# --------------------------
mutable struct VariableA
    main_diffeq
    params_for_diffeq::Array # a in main_diffeq_A
    B_component
end

function main_diffeq_A(a)
    dx = -a * x
end
# --------------------------


# --------------------------
mutable struct VariableB
    main_diffeq
    params_for_diffeq::Array  # b in main_diffeq_B
end

function main_diffeq_B(b)
    dx = b * x
end
# --------------------------


# the elements for my differential equations
B = VariableB(main_diffeq_B, [1])
A = VariableA(main_diffeq_A, [1], (B,))
```

In this case, I have only one B component in A.
But in other cases, there may be different numbers of B component.
The following is my function, and it will be put into `ODEProblem(MyDiffEq!(A), u, t, p)`

```
function MyDiffEq!(A)
    # something...
end
```

The goal will be equal to:

```
function MyDiffEq!(du, u, p, t)
    # A  -->  dA = -a * A + B
    du[1] = -u[1] * p[1] + u[2]

    # B
    du[2] = u[2] * p[2]
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried to read you question a couple of times, but I am struggling understanding your goal. Could you try to simplify the question to a minimal example that does not have unnecessary details?

Comment: I'm sorry my question confused you. The goal is that my differential equation is composed of a main_diffeq, and some components(the number is not sure). For example, it may be dA = A + B or dA = A + B + B2. I don't know how to transform my struct A (A will contain all information.) into the standard function written in (du,u,p,t). I edit the question again, and I hope you'll understand, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [ModelingToolkit.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/ModelingToolkit.jl) library which allows for programmatic construction of differential equation functions. The example from the README builds the Lorenz equations:

```
using ModelingToolkit

# Define some variables
@parameters t σ ρ β
@variables x(t) y(t) z(t)
@derivatives D'~t
eqs = [D(x) ~ σ*(y-x),
       D(y) ~ x*(ρ-z)-y,
       D(z) ~ x*y - β*z]
de = ODESystem(eqs)
f = ODEFunction(de, [x,y,z], [σ,ρ,β])
prob = ODEProblem(f,[1.0,1.0,1.0],(0.0,100.0),[1.0,3.0,2.0])
```

You can then define new variables that are the combined expressions and use those in the derivative equations. This library is under continued development (current day: 4/27/2019) and future features will make it easier to combine pre-built differential equation models to more easily build large systems of differential equations.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't find this library before. I'll give it a try, thanks a lot!

Comment: ModelingToolkit.jl works for me!
I'm just curious that the Callback Functions hasn't implemented in ModelingToolkit.jl right?

Comment: Yeah, but it's on the shortlist: https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/ModelingToolkit.jl/issues/38

Comment: I understand. Thanks for your response!